# How to add two values of the same column in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following table?

```
ID     COL    VALUE
1       A     10
2       B     10
3       C     10
4       D     10
5       E     10
```

Output:

```
ID     COL    VALUE
1       A     10
2       B     20
3       C     30
4       D     40
5       E     50
```

Comment: Are you asking for a cumulative sum?  If not, please elaborate more on how you are getting those expected values.

Comment: Also, please tag your DBMS (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.).

Comment: I am using SQl server. I tried  your query but m getting an error like incorrect syntax near 'order'.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: version=12.0.2269.0 (sql server 2014)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the query that gives you that error.  SQL Server 2014 supports a windowed SUM function.

Comment: I tried the code now but i am not getting the result that i am expecting.. I am getting the output like this    Id Col Value
1 A     10
2 B     30
3 C     60
4 D     100
5 E     150

Comment: Are the values in your table exactly as you have stated in your question?  Please confirm the contents of your table.

Comment: Yes.. in question values are correct

Comment: Hey Siyual..Thank you so much. Problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your (deleted) comment `in output it is taking up the sum of the upper values`, it sounds like you're wanting a cumulative `SUM()`.

You can do this with a windowed function:

```
Select  Id, Col, Sum(Value) Over (Order By Id) As Value
From    YourTable
```

> Output

```
Id  Col Value
1   A   10
2   B   20
3   C   30
4   D   40
5   E   50
```

Comment: Id Col Value
1 A     10
2 B     30
3 C     60
4 D     100
5 E     150              I am getting the o/p like this

Answer (score 0):

Please make use of the the below code to obtain the **cumulative sum**. The code is working as expected with SQL Server 2012.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID int, COL CHAR(2), VALUE int)
INSERT @Table
(ID,COL,[VALUE])
VALUES
(1,'A',10),
(2,'B',10),
(3,'C',10),
(4,'D',10),
(5,'E',10)

SELECT t.ID,t.COL,SUM(VALUE)  OVER (ORDER BY t.ID) AS VALUE
FROM @Table t
```

Answer (score -1):

Not really sure what you are asking for. If my assumption is correct, you want to SUM the contents of a column and group it. 
`Select sum(value), col
from table
group by col`

Comment: By this query..i ll get the total of column(value).see in output it is taking up the sum of the upper values...i want output like value1=10, value2= value1+10, value3=value2+10 and so on..Hope now u got the idea, Thanks!!

Comment: You only want the highest value? You can use `select max(value),col from table group by col` - I apologize if I am not understanding still.. It is not clear to me what you need.